# matching multiple words with enumerateSubstringsInRange in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to match the string below but unfortunately it only gives me "nope" as the result. Can anyone help? thanks in advance!

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"darn thing suddenly erupted without any warning.";
NSString *findMe = @"suddenly erupted";

[text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [text length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([findMe isEqualToString:substring] ) {
        NSLog(@"found it");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"nope");
    }
   }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is only enumerating separate words. "suddenly erupted" are two words.

Why don't you use `-rangeOfSubstring:` in order to find whether text contains some substring? For example:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[text mutableString] rangeOfString:findMe].location == NSNotFound ? @"nope" : @"found it");
```

Comment: sorry, it's a requirement that I use  [text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [text length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) because I am passing the substringRange to another method.

Comment: @ilteris `[text rangeOfString:findMe]` will return `NSRange` that you can pass.

Comment: it would display nope every time bcz put NSLog on substring you may find that your substirng is word every time like first time "darn" second time "thing" and so on you are trying to match with 2 word "suddenly erupted" so it check this with "suddenly" only so it give you result nope.

as Kirstein's answer suggested use

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't mention this was an NSMutableAttributedString object. So rangeOfString doesn't work for me. I edited the title accordingly. My bad, it's little late here.

Comment: I don't think that `enumerateSubstringsInRange` will work either. but you can get `NSString` from `NSMutableAttributedString` by `[[myMutableAttributedString mutableString] copy]`

Answer (score 0):

enumerateSubstringsInRange have options like

```
NSStringEnumerationByLines
NSStringEnumerationBySentences
NSStringEnumerationByParagraphs
NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
NSStringEnumerationByWords
```

if you have words to compare means it will work

e.g

```
 NSString *text = @"darn thing suddenlyerupted without any warning.";
 NSString *findMe = @"suddenlyerupted";
```

so you cant compare sub string. You need to customize the block or move to some other option.

Comment: can you elaborate on the customize the block or recommend any other option?

Comment: Better go with rangeOfSubstring comparison.